# Printing a webpage with varying div sizes

Tags: javascript, printing

Is there any way to make it so divs do not get cut in half when printing multiple pages?  There are divs that I am trying to print that vary in size and I would like it to print so that none of them are cut off and the full div boxes appear on a single page.  Maybe there is a way to calculate the height of each div and if one puts it over the height of the page, then put it on the next page?  I know I could get the length of the text within each div and maybe do it that way, but how would I go about designating a div to be printed on another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS property `page-break-inside`:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-break-props